# Can't importe scikit-image in python 3.7

Tags: scikit-image

I have successfully installed the package scikit-image in my python project. However, I can't seem to import it to my python code. It seems it has a problem with the hyphen in the package. I have tried to install skimage, but it pip does not want to install this package and suggest I should install scikit-image instead.  Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install:

```
pip install scikit-image
```

To check which version is installed:

```
pip show scikit-image
```

To use in Python:

```
import skimage
```

or, something more specific:

```
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
```

If that doesn't work, run each of the following commands and paste the output into your question:

```
which pip
pip -V
which python
python -V
```